# What is function User.findOrCreate doing and when is it called in passport?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I can't find documentation on this function and therefor I can't make it work right. When is that function being called, what is it doing and what is it taking as first parameters? I'm trying to get access token from passport, but can't reach it anyhow.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID:   APP_ID,
    clientSecret:   APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/",
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({// what are these parameters?}, function (err, user) {
        // when is this function called and what is it doing? 
       });

  }
));
```

How can I get access token from passport?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`User.findOrCreate` is a made-up function that represents whatever function you have to find a user by Facebook ID, or to create one if the user doesn't exist. I think your first problem is that your callback URL is just going to your root, so you probably are never getting to that function.

Your callback URL should be like `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`.

And then handle that URL:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

At this point Authentication is complete. `accessToken` is returned to you -- "this is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf". You should save this off in some table where you store access tokens for a user. `profile` is the other key variable because that is the info about the user (what info depends on the service).

**What you do inside that function is up to you**. So, make your own `User.findOrCreate`. Here is the code from passport for Facebook with some comments to explain it. This assumes you are using something like MongoDB and have a `User` table. `User` in this case is whatever variable you declared that can interface with the `User` table.

```
//Use facebook strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        //check user table for anyone with a facebook ID of profile.id
        User.findOne({
            'facebook.id': profile.id 
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            //No user was found... so create a new user with values from Facebook (all the profile. stuff)
            if (!user) {
                user = new User({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    email: profile.emails[0].value,
                    username: profile.username,
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    //now in the future searching on User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id } will match because of this next line
                    facebook: profile._json
                });
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                //found user. Return
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }
));
```

Personally I also use a "membership" table to track multiple accounts per user (so they can authenticate with multiple accounts), as I set it up through mongoose. This is actually where I store that access token. I prefer this to having a facebook column in the user table.... but that is up to you.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var membershipSchema = new Schema({
    provider:  String,
    providerUserId:  String,
    accessToken: String,
    userId: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    dateAdded: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Membership', membershipSchema);
```

and as such, my version of `User.findOrCreate` starts off like this:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    Membership.findOne({
        providerUserId: profile.id
    }, function(err,membershipData) {
            //blah blah blah
```

where membership is that model above, and is defined as a variable as:

```
var Membership =  require('./models/membership.js')
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this work for me, but it's not. You were right about that I'm never calling my callback function. Could you just tell me why is this function which is in your case Membership.findOne({.. needed to be in code? I'm trying to put it without, but it seems like it's never terminating.

Comment: @Tommz It's in the code to save off the profile information to the database. In it's simplest form, you can try just returning `return done(null, profile);` in the `function(accessToken...` as it needs to return something or else, like you said, it will seem like it never terminates.

Comment: Yea, but problem occurs when I want to do this when I have code like this and getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436387/typeerror-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined-at-strategy-app-get-passport-a . Also, I've tried already return done(null, profile) in function(accessToken... but then I get error that 'object' can't be used as function, meaning on "done" I guess :\

Comment: @MikeSmithDev this might be a stupid question, but do you determine whether the same user is already signed up with another social provider by email (so only if the provider returns the same email address for the social account you know it's the same as one who already is in your database)?

Comment: @MaximZubarev yes that is indeed what I do. If no one is found with the provider id, then next check against an email to ensure you don't create another account for an existing member. Didn't include that in the code above, but would be in the `if (!user) {` section.

Answer (score 15):

If you would like to use `findOrCreate`, try the npm package [mongoose-findorcreate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-findorcreate), or [supergoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supergoose)

e.g. `mongoose-findorcreate`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

var findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({ facebookId: Number});
UserSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 'clientID',
        clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
        callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          console.log('A new uxer from "%s" was inserted', user.facebookId);
          return cb(err, user);
        });
    }
));
```