# Cannot use aouth in Slack

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, integration, slack-api, slack

I try to use Oauth 2.0 in Slack.

What I have done so far is;
I created a application from here; https://api.slack.com/apps
I get the `client id` and `client secret` from app credentials.

And then, I install `passport-slack` as `npm install passport-slack`

As https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack suggests I added the following code with mu client id and client secret.

```
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ SlackId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

But it throws an error as;

```
[ReferenceError: SlackStrategy is not defined]
```

I required `passport-slack` as;

```
var passport = require("passport-slack");
```

Why I cannot find the user? And it gives me an error?

Answer (score 2):

First thing:

> var passport = require("passport-slack");

You should import passport like this:

```
var passport = require("passport");
```

Passport is an authentification middleware, which use 'strategies'. Passport-slack is one of these strategies. Here, you just want the middleware.

Second thing:

> [ReferenceError: SlackStrategy is not defined]

You need to import the SlackStrategy like this :

```
var SlackStrategy = require("passport-slack").Strategy;
```

This time, you want a strategy, so that's the way we import it.

Last thing:

> Why I cannot find the user? And it gives me an error?

I'm not really sure about what you mean here, but i guess you get an error telling you 'User is undefined' or something like that. To learn more about this `User.findOne()` function, you can take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport).