# Method findOrCreate() is not resolved from my user model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement social authentication in Node.js with Passport whereby I need to use findOrCreate() while configuring my Facebook Authentication Strategy.
This is my facebook.js where configuration happens:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook');

var User = require('../models/user');
var config = require('../_config');
var init = require('./init');

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 1900216703426978,
    clientSecret: 'f2c2ee6069de323109cb9347fad01026',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/passport/facebook/callback"
},

User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    return cb(err, user);
})

));

init();

module.exports = passport;
```

and this is my models/user.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return user;

}
```

Based on the documentation from http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html, 
I supposed that findOrCreate() is an built-in method available for models. 
However in my facebook.js there is an underline under findOrCreate() mentioning that the method is unresolved.

I had made sure I'm requiring the right directory and I also attempted a solution by this link: [What is function User.findOrCreate doing and when is it called in passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport/20431414) which also requires a method, findOne() that is unresolved as well.

Do I create these functions in my models/user.js or there's something wrong with my user model? Let me know if I'm missing providing any code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hook up sequalize to read your models, something like:

```
// ./database.js

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(yourDatabaseOpts)
const User = require('./models/user')(sequelize, Sequelize)
module.exports = { User }
```

Then, when you want to use the User, do e.g. the following:

```
const User = require('./database').User
User.findOrCreate(...)
```

Comment: This is a very dumb question but what should I write in (yourDatabaseOpts)? Can you show me an example?

Comment: This will probably help you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport