# `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ` when I try to login with `passport-google-oauth20`

Tags: express, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

When I tried to implement Google OAuth into my node app using `passport-google-oauth20`, I got a problem.

Whenever I attempt the first login to the *secrets* page with the following code, I fail to authenticate and got redirected to the `/login` page, also got the error saying `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` at the line serializing the user, even though `newUser` has been saved in the mongoDB.

However, I can successfully authenticate and login to the *secrets* page the second login attempt.

What's happening behind the scenes where the error occurs? How can I successfully authenticate the user when the first login attempt?

I referred to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport/41355218) as well.

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets"
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!foundUser) {
          const newUser = new User({
            googleId: profile.id
          });

          newUser.save((err, savedUser) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return done(null, savedUser);
          });
        }
        return done(null, foundUser);
      });
    }
));
```

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);     ///// The error occurs at this line /////
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

```js
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get(
  "/auth/google/secrets",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "/secrets",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
  })
);

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) return res.render("secrets");
  res.redirect("/login");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is within the verify callback. Calling `return done(null, savedUser)` will occur asynchronously. This means that the program will first call `return done(null, foundUser)` then after the saving call `return done(null, savedUser)`.

To resolve the issue I would recommend refactoring the verify callback to use async/await. This makes it easier to reason about and reduces the chances of race conditions from conflicting callbacks.

Example Refactor:

```js
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  try {
    let foundUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
    
    if (!foundUser) {
      const newUser = new User({
        googleId: profile.id
      });

      await newUser.save();
      return done(null, newUser);
    }

    return done(null, foundUser);
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
}));
```